# Serving static files with ring/compojure - from a war

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

Using ring (and the lein-ring tools) - I am able to serve up static files from "resources" etc as per the docs when running in development - however - when I package things up via lien uberwar I have no idea how to make it serve those files when running in a container. I see conflicting docs on wrap-resource, or setting :resource-path but none seem to work.

Comment: For Google App Engine I could just but the static files directly in the `war/` directory. Template files (I use soy) actually stay in the `resource/` directory and somehow get compiled into the war directory. I suppose this is not possible / doesn't work in your case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per Compojure's [Getting Started Wiki](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Getting-Started), put `route/resources` below your paths:

```
(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] "<h1>Hello World Wide Web!</h1>")
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

...and then, create a folder `resources/public` in your project, put your static files there. When referring to these files, the `/resources/public` is implicit, so you can write something like: `(include-css "/css/site.css")`.

Here is [an example that deploys to cloudbees](https://github.com/michaelneale/clojure-bootstrap).

Comment: is that supposed to be `resources/public` instead of `resrouce/public`?

Comment: sorry Michael, I can't spell! I was trying to say the `resources` directory is supposed to be in plural form, I think.

Answer (score 20):

`compojure.route/resources` should do what you want.

Just put the files in `resources/public` and then add a route `(resources "/")` near the end of your routes list.

You need a fairly recent lein-ring for this to work correctly; older versions of lein-ring don't support the resources directory for public assets.