# How do you set the filepath for css in hiccup with Clojure using the html5 tag?

Tags: css, html, clojure, path, hiccup

I am learning the very basics of web-developing with Clojure, but cannot seem to get my css to work using hiccup. I have tested several possible paths to the file, tried setting the link manually using tags, and even tried adding an `html5,` line at the top of the .css file. Nothing seems to be working. I am sure there is an idiomatic way to do it, that I just don't know. If someone could tell me how to use hiccup and css together so that it is guaranteed to work, I would be very grateful.

I have this tree structure for my directory:

```
.____resources
| |____public
|  |____404.html
|  |____500.html
|  |____home.css <- I want to see this augmenting the html5 in home from the landing.clj, below.
|____src
 |____clojuregrade
  |____landing.clj <- home function with html5 is here.
  |____web.clj
```

I have this function in landing.clj above:

```
(defn home [& [weights grades error]]
  (html5
    [:head
    [:title ...]
     (include-css "/public/home.css")] ;; <- Is this right?
    [:body
   (form-to [:post "/"]
     (text-area ...)]
     (text-area ...)]
     (submit-button "process"))]))
```

I have this code from home.css, above:

```
body {
    background-color: #BAC4E8;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Garamond;
    color: #29507A;

}
```

note: I have abridged the above code to try and generalize the question to make it useful for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you do not need to prefix it with `public`, either `/home.css` or `home.css` should be enough. If you are using Compojure note that you need to expose your resources explicitly (check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7820392/206020).

Comment: Adding (routes/resources "/") under my GET method did the trick! Great answer. Clear and consise. Thank you.