# Google App Engine css not loading after deployment with Luminus

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, luminus

I created a small application in clojure using luminus framework. When I run the app using lein run everything works well. It loads css and js properly but when I create a war file and deploy on google app engine, stylesheets don't work. I tried the solution given on this link: [Serving static files with ring/compojure - from a war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816465/serving-static-files-with-ring-compojure-from-a-war) but it is still not working. May be there is something specific to luminus which I am missing. When I inspect it and look at console it shows this error

> GET unbound:  net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

I think I am missing something in luminus Can someone help please. Thanks

Comment: Something is misconfigured and the string 'unbound' is being set as the target of some `<link>`. Can you post more information about how you're set up?

Comment: Do you use Selmer? Could you, please, publish the source of the page?

Comment: Yes I am using Selmer, Basically it is talking adding servlet-context in the path when I run it con GAE. So path is coming as                                  '<script src="Unbound: #'talky-alerts.layout/*app-context*/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'

Comment: I think I figured it out. According to this documentation [link] (http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/html_templating.md) Selmer will prepend the servlet-context automatically until it is not present. So instead of using Selmer style we can use link tag `<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` directly to get the files. But is there any way to use Selmer style tag without prepending servlet-context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out why this is happening. The Selmer style tag `{% style "filename" %}` will generate an HTML script tag and prepend the value of the servlet-context key to the URI. When servlet-context key is not present then the original URI is set. So when you give `src = "css/filename"` it gives the `src = servlet-context + "css/filename"` which can be seen in inspect. So to avoid it either do not associate servlet-context or use normal stylesheet `<link>` to add your static css/js files. 
To remove servlet-context Just comment out `:servlet-context *app-context*` line form `render` function in `layout.clj` file and it will start working.